# Replace a value in a string

Tags: java, regex, string, wildcard

I have a list of strings which are like

```
x[0]="My speed=300 km/h";  
x[1]="My speed=0 km/h";  
x[3]="My speed=25 km/h";
```

and i want for each line to replace the speed (300,0....) with one of my variables.

Till now i am using a wildcard like this

```
String newSpeed= x[3].replaceAll("eed=.. km","eed="+myVariable+" km");
```

My problem is that i can't predict how many digits the number will be, how can i replace it correctly no matter how many digits the number is?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\\d+` to match one or more digit chars.

```
x[3].replaceAll("eed=\\d+ km","eed="+myVariable+" km");
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is using the substring:

```
String newSpeed = x[3].substring(0,8)+myVariable+" km";
```

Comment: The string is bigger and more random than the example , that's why i needed to use replace

Answer (score 1):

you could Try Pattern.quote

```
 x[3].replaceAll( Pattern.quote("eed=\\d+ km","eed="+myVariable+" km"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will change every string in array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
  {
       x[i].replaceAll("eed=\\d+ km","eed="+myVariable+" km"); 
       // d matches [0-9] and other digit characters + to multiple digits
  }
```

Hope you found my code helpful.